# Custom error code for missing path parameters - serverless

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a lambda function defined as

```
getDta:
    handler: src/handlers/data/get.getAll
    events:
      - http:
          path: groups/{groupsId}/data
          method: get
          cors: true
          private: true
```

If I use API like `http://localhost:3000/groups//data` where `groupsId` is missing from path please take a look again.

In this case serverless itself return `404 - Route not found`. How can I override this error to `400 - Bad request`?

I appreciate your suggestion! (edited)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function for `path: groups/data` and return `400 - Bad Request`. But `404` is not a `Bad Request` code.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, It should be `400 - Bad request`, I have edited question description

Comment: Is it really a good idea? Is there no any cleaner way? Is there nothing like configuration in serverless.yml?

Comment: And it is not like `path: groups/data` as you mentioned but it is like `path: groups//data`.

Comment: There is a catch all https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/api-gateway-update-new-features-simplify-api-development/